# Shell script - No such file error

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
local dept=0
while [ $n < 5 ]
do
  echo $n
  $n++
done
```

this code returns error `7: cannot open 5: No such file`
Where should I change?

Comment: Start by reading a great guide about shell-scripting, e.g. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `$n -lt 5`. Bash reads the `<` there as redirection, so it tries to open a file named `5` and feed its contents to a command named `$n`

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
while [ $n -lt 5 ]
do
  echo $n
  let n=$n+1
done
```

Comment: I used `while [$n -lt 5]` it returns `[: 7: missing ]`

Comment: And `while [ $n -lt 5 ]` returns: ` [: 7: -lt: unexpected operator `

Comment: You have a strange bash :-) What do you get back from `bash -version` ?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
while [[ "$n" < 5 ]]
do
   echo $n
   ((n++))
done
~
```

Answer (score 1):

Most portable (POSIX sh-compliant) way is:

```
#!/bin/sh -ef
n=0
while [ "$n" -lt 5 ]; do
    echo "$n"
    n=$(($n + 1))
done
```

Note:

- `"$n"` - quotes around `$n` help against crashing with missing operand error, if `n` is not initialized.
- `[` (AKA `test`) and `-lt` - is a safe and fairly portable way to check for simple arithmetic clauses.
- `$((...))` is a safe and portable way to do arithmetic expansion (i.e. running calculations); note `$n` inside this expansion - while bash would allow you to use just `n`, the standard and portable way is to use `$n`.